# What is the cutoff for number of activity targets in the UI, and can it be changed?

Tags: activities, ui, edit

Drupal 7, CiviCRM  5.39.1

When I edit an activity with a few contacts, I am given the opportunity to edit those contacts. Once the threshold of somewhere between 50-60 contacts is crossed, however, there is no longer the opportunity to edit the contacts on an activity.

What is driving the difference in behavior of the UI?

[image: Edit Activity Screen With Fewer Contacts][image: Edit Activity Screen with More Contacts]

Answer (score 3):

50 is maximum number of Target contact that can be edited from UI.

More details on [CRM-15472](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-15472)

But i think it can be changed by sending a small PR to core or implementing hook to make the field editable.

Comment: I support for creating a setting in Civi so that it can be altered from UI or api or $civicrm_settings variable